# Google Sheets: Generate column in query based on reference range matches?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-filter

I'm no sheets expert, and I couldn't find the answer searching likely due to not using right search terms. Sorry if this is already answered and sorry if it's not possible.

We have a data source that has inaccurate location codes for employees, so we reference a separate employee and location list often. It would be nice to be able to generate a list with *one formula* that adds a column which populates based on the reference range.

Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vEpF84dxMeUun-H0vDFzfX5sitjdeoHgiv3C7fAiZpY/edit?usp=sharing

In this example there is a main data set and a reference for location: 
[image: Data to combine]

The current solution is to populate a new row separately from the query. The drawbacks are extra formulas for blank cells (especially a problem with huge data sets), and the inability to sort the list by the new location column. Is there a solution using arrays or something that can just add the new column based on name column matches, so I can sort them at the same time? See picture for current solution and my wish

[image]

Question (are you ready): Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula would be:

```
=QUERY({G2:I,ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(H2:H,{C2:C,B2:B},2,0))}, 
     "select Col4, Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col3='passed' order by Col4 , Col2 ")
```

[image: Create column in query based on reference range matches]

**Functions used:**
+ [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
+ [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
+ [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: I just found out about  vlookup in arrays thank you! I wish filters could work with them too.

Comment: _" I wish filters could work with them too."_. They have their place in arrays as well when needed. Please have a look at [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/136329/117311) or [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137356/117311) answer as examples.